# Using Webcam in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webcam, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

I have a rails app with a sign-up page, where users fill in a form with their details. I want to add a field for user's picture: rather than uploading it, I want the user to take a picture using their webcam. The picture is supposed to be saved to the disk and the DB to be updated with its name and path.

How can I do this? I know that the storage was previously handled by `paperclip` but it is nowadays done using `Active Storage`, but what about using the webcam? googling "ruby gem webcam" and limiting results to the last year has been surprisingly unhelpful, with most results being porn-related.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the webcam then you'll need to handle that side of things in JavaScript. You would need to use the [`getUserMedia` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) to get access to the camera stream. Once you've got that, you can capture a still by writing frames from the camera into a canvas, then exporting the canvas to an image with [`Canvas.toDataBlob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob).

Some browsers expose more [access to the camera for capturing images](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/imagecapture#capabilities_and_settings), but you'll still get a blob eventually.

Once you've got that, you can add it to a [`FormData` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) and submit to your Rails app at which point Active Storage can take over storing the file.

Comment: Isn't there any relevant gem for doing this?

Comment: It’s all done in the front end, in the browser, and Ruby does not run in the front end. If there was a gem for it, it would be for Opal Ruby, so it could be converted to JS, but I don’t know of one.

Comment: ruby itself doesn't, a rails app does handle the frontend

Comment: It’s still JS that runs on the front end ‍♂️